# Search full name in database with PHP when first and lastname are in different fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I store the firstname and lastname in separate fields in the database. But I have to search the database for a full name. How can I do that in an efficient way using `SQL` and `PHP`?

Comment: What type of SQL? MySQL? MSSQL?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that I use MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using something like..

```
SELECT
       CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName,lastName) AS name
FROM 
       table
WHERE 
       name LIKE '%$keywords%'
```

Comment: Make sure that the field name is also indexed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)='Steven Dobbelaere';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) like '%keyword%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from names where CONCAT('first','last') = 'FirstLast';
```

Where the fields are first and last. Note that the CONCAT function in MySQL can do multiple arguements, so you could say:

```
CONCAT('first',' ','last')
```

To get 'John Doe' as the string you're comparing to; at this point, you can use = or like and compare just as if you were comparing against a normal string.